# Rotate Venn diagram plot made with the eulerr package

Tags: r, venn-diagram, eulerr

I'm able to make a Venn diagram like below with the `eulerr` package in R with this code. However, the plot is rotated vertically. How can I rotate the plot so that it's wider than taller?

```
library(eulerr)
set.seed(3)
group1_size <- 13622
group2_size <- 40219    
group3_size <- 17120

group2_group1_group3 = as.integer(group1_size*0.2)
group1_group3_size <- as.integer(group1_size*0.6) - group2_group1_group3 
group1_group2_size <- as.integer(group1_size*0.3) - group2_group1_group3 
group3_size_group2_size <- as.integer(group3_size*0.35) - group2_group1_group3 
group1_only_direct <- group1_size - group1_group3_size - group1_group2_size - group2_group1_group3 
group2_only <- group2_size - group1_group2_size - group3_size_group2_size - group2_group1_group3 
group3_only_direct <- group3_size - group3_size_group2_size - group1_group3_size - group2_group1_group3 


fit <- euler(c(Group1 = group1_only_direct,
               Group2 = group3_only_direct,
               Group3 = group2_only,
               "Group1&Group3" = group1_group3_size,
               "Group1&Group2" = group1_group2_size,
               "Group3&Group2" = group3_size_group2_size,
               "Group2&Group1&Group3" = group2_group1_group3 
               )
             )
plot(fit,
     quantities = list(fontsize = 12),
     main = "Example Diagram")
```

[image]